# How to get html control by ID that has hyphens?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

I have a front end written in html that I am converting to asp, and many of the controls have names with "-" in them.  This is causing crazy headaches, as there is no time to rename everything, and the ctrl-f and replace somehow breaks my css.  Is there any way to access these controls in the code behind while they have the dashes?  I have tried the code below.

```
//Can find when there is no dash in it, but that breaks the css after find/replace of full solution
HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.FindControl("page-list");
body.Attributes.Add("class", GlobalVariables.webAppSkin);

//I have also tried this, but logout stays null
WebControl logout = (WebControl)Page.FindControl("logout-link");
```

This is the html control:

```
<body id="page-list">
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.Page.FindControl(@"page-list");` I'm not sure if that will work, but I'll try it a bit later.

Comment: Yup, still can't grab that pesky control.

Comment: @Greg "page-list" doesn't have any characters that need to be escaped, so it wouldn't make a difference to use a string literal.

Comment: can you show your html markup..? I wonder if you are missing the `runat="server"` attribute try `<body id="page-list" runat="server>`

Comment: I believe this is not possible. In addition, you can't find controls in code behind that are not marked runat="server". You will need to rename in HTML markup and CSS and add the above attribute. Find and replace.

Comment: runat="server" gives me issues because then it declares and instance of the variable in Default.aspx.designer.cs, which does not compile with the dashes...

Comment: Exactly, so you need to find and replace the ids with .Net compliant ids, i.e., pageList or something similar.

Comment: It should be trivial to replace the hyphens with underscores, then go through and fix whatever problems you have with the CSS.

Comment: @mason It becomes much less trivial when you're using something like jQuery UI which inserts IDs with hyphens, and doesn't do that if you've already declared IDs, so that, if you declare the requisite IDs manually in order to then target them in code-behind, you get this error. At least, that's the frustration I just discovered a few minutes ago.

Comment: @TylerH JQuery UI? That's a name I haven't heard in a very long time. I feel your pain. Best of luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, that's not gonna happen.

You cannot have an element with an id containing "-", and still be a `runat="server"` ASP.NET control.

Microsoft's docs about the control's IDs states:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx

> Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.

If you tried adding `runat="server"` to the body tag you showed: `<body id="page-list">`, it would give you the following line in `aspx.designer.cs`:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl page-list;
```

Which is obviously throwing an exception on C# syntax.

Comment: so ASP crashes by design under valid html. no wonder I dislike this platform, a designed bug, how wonderfull.

Answer (score 4):

`<body id="page-list">` is not a HTML Control (i.e. an instance of (a subclass of) `System.Web.UI.Control` because it doesn't have the `runat="server"` attribute. If you were to add `runat="server"` then you would get a JIT compile-time error message informing you that "page-list" is not a valid identifier.

ASP.NET Web Forms 4.0 added the `ClientIDMode` attribute, however it doesn't allow you to set a completely custom ID attribute value. There's no easy solution for this without using [`<asp:Literal>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal) or implementing your own control (or my preferred option: switching to ASP.NET MVC).

Answer (score 1):

You can access controls in code behind with their ID if you write runat="server". Here is the example for your case

```
<body runat="server" id="testID">
```

In code behind you can access it like this:

body.Attributes.Add("class", value);

Comment: runat="server" gives me issues because then it declares and instance of the variable in Default.aspx.designer.cs, which does not compile with the dashes...

Comment: Change the ID without dash in this case and in the css write .body { css script }

Comment: The whole point of the question is how to do it while retaining the dashes.